# Errors while updating symfony 2.8 to symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I am updating symfony version from 2.8 to symfony 3.4 here is my composer.json

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.5.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.3",
        "twig/extensions": "~1",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.1",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.1",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.1",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^2.1",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^2.1",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.1",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "~1.2",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "~1.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.0",
        "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "~1.1",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "~2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0.0",
        "avalanche123/imagine-bundle": "~2.1",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "knplabs/knp-components": "~1.2.1",
        "kbsali/redmine-api": "~1.0",
        "exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle": "^0.2.2",
        "doctrine/migrations": "^1",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4",
        "react/zmq": "0.3.*",
        "cboden/ratchet": "0.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/translation": "~2.8",
        "symfony/templating": "~3.0.9",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "~3.0.9",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "~3.0.9",
        "symfony/security-core": "~3.0.9",
        "symfony/routing": "~3.0.9",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.1",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "~2.7",
        "symfony/options-resolver": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~2.1",
        "symfony/debug": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/filesystem": "~3.0.9",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/config": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/class-loader": "~3.0.9",
        "symfony/asset": "~3.0.9",
        "symfony/form": "~2.1",
        "symfony/property-access": "~3.0.9",
        "symfony/serializer": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/console": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/yaml": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/process": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/security": "~2.8",
        "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "~2.8.9",
        "symfony/intl": "~3.2.9"
    }
```

I have an error, when i am updating

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
>
> ```
>   Unable to parse file "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/templating.xml".
>
>   [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>   [ERROR 1871] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}defaults': This element is
> ```
>
> not expected. Expected is (
>   {http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}service )
>
> ```
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
> ```
>
> handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> ```
>   [RuntimeException]                                                         
>   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
> ```

I moved logs and cache folders to new directory var.
Moved console to bin directory and replace `require_once _DIR__.'/bootstrap.php.cache'; with require _DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';`

Changed version of symfony in composer and run this command

```
composer update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies
```

Please help to solve it.

Comment: How are you performing the upgrade? Can you describe the changes you made/commands being executed? From what it looks like TwigBundle uses a new feature not yet supported by your Symfony/DependencyInjection component. Either temporarily downgrading TwigBundle or updating the DI-component could help

Comment: @dbrumann Thank you for replay, edited my question

Comment: Your Symfony components are limited to 2.8 maybe you want to replace the entries with: `^2.8.9 || ^3.4` for all the symfony components. Instead of manually changing this and then running update you could also try to use `composer require symfony/symfony:^3.4 --update-with-all-dependencies` instead. This will try to update the version and also write this version constraint to your composer.json for you.

Comment: Your composer.json files seems to have some serious issues starting with the php version.  Start a fresh 3.4 project then add your additional dependencies one by one.  Assuming there are 3.4 compatible versions available of all your dependencies, then you will end at least up with a more or less clean composer.json file you can start with.